# Over and Under game.

Tags: c#, properties

(C#) This game will have a computer generate a random number and the user will have to continue guessing until they find out what it is. My problem is that I have to display the best score which is the lowest amount of guesses out of all the times they play and I don't know how to do it using a property.

```
class OverUnder
{
    string playAgain = "";

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 101);

    int guess = 1;
    int userGuess;



    public string playerGuess()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number from 1 - 100");
        string playerGuess = Console.ReadLine();
        return playerGuess;
    }
    public string userPlayAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? Yes or No");
        string userPlayAgain = Console.ReadLine();
        return userPlayAgain;
    }
    public void playGame()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(randomNumber);

        do
        {
            userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(playerGuess());


            if (randomNumber > userGuess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is LOW");
                Console.WriteLine("# of guesses: " + guess);
                Console.WriteLine("Best score: " + guess);
                guess++;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else if (randomNumber < userGuess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is HIGH");
                Console.WriteLine("# of guesses: " + guess);
                Console.WriteLine("Best score: " + guess);
                guess++;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            if (userGuess == randomNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You got it! Congratulations, You Win!");
                Console.WriteLine("# of guesses: " + guess);
                Console.WriteLine("Best score: " + guess);
                Console.ReadLine();
                playAgain = userPlayAgain();
            }
        } while (userGuess != randomNumber || playAgain == "Yes" );
    }
```

It displays what the computer randomized just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a field on the class to keep the best score:

```
class OverUnder
{
    int bestScore = Int.MaxValue; // initally max to reset it after the first game

    ...
}
```

Then when the user guesses, set its value. Don't forget to reset the number of guesses to zero.

```
    if (userGuess == randomNumber)
        {
            if (guess < bestScore)
                bestScore = guess;
            Console.WriteLine("You got it! Congratulations, You Win!");
            Console.WriteLine("# of guesses: " + guess);
            Console.WriteLine("Best score: " + bestScore.Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
            playAgain = userPlayAgain();
            guess = 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another variable that gets held and set when the user has guessed the random number.

Something like.

```
class OverUnder
{
    string playAgain = "";

    Random random = new Random();

    public OverUnder()
    {
        randomNumber = random.Next(1, 101);
    }

    int randomNumber = 0;
    int bestScore = int.MaxValue;
    int guess = 1;
    int userGuess;


    public string playerGuess()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number from 1 - 100");
        string playerGuess = Console.ReadLine();
        return playerGuess;
    }

    public string userPlayAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again? Yes or No");
        string userPlayAgain = Console.ReadLine();
        return userPlayAgain;
    }

    public void playGame()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(randomNumber);

        do
        {
            userGuess = Convert.ToInt32(playerGuess());


            if (randomNumber > userGuess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is LOW");
                Console.WriteLine("# of guesses: " + guess);
                Console.WriteLine("Best score: " + guess);
                guess++;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else if (randomNumber < userGuess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is HIGH");
                Console.WriteLine("# of guesses: " + guess);
                Console.WriteLine("Best score: " + guess);
                guess++;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            if (userGuess == randomNumber)
            {
                if (guess < bestScore)
                    bestScore = guess;

                Console.WriteLine("You got it! Congratulations, You Win!");
                Console.WriteLine("# of guesses: " + guess);
                Console.WriteLine("Best score: " + bestScore);
                Console.ReadLine();
                playAgain = userPlayAgain();
            }
        } while (userGuess != randomNumber || playAgain == "Yes");
    }
}
```

Note i did fix some compiler errors, but you will see the field bestScore which is set to the max int value. When the player guesses the correct number then you check if their guess count is less than their best score. If it is, then you simple set bestScore to the guess amount.

Cheers.